# Node.js & Webdriver.io with Selenium Standalone Server can´t use custom profiles

Tags: node.js, selenium, firefox, webdriver-io, geckodriver

I am trying to launch a Firefox browser via Selenium using a **[Custom Profile](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/)**. I downloaded the latest **[geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)** and included it with the following:

```
java -Dwebdriver.firefox.driver="C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\geckodriver.exe" -jar selenium-server.jar
```

**Note:** I am using Selenium Standalone Server 3.5.0.

Then, in my node script I use:

```
const options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        firefox_profile:"C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/Prnlx0rh6w.bookmarks_player"
    }
} 

const client = webdriverio.remote(options).init();
```

It seems that it worked when I look into Selenium logs. Because there will be not created a temp profile in the Windows `temp` folders ( as it would for a new session), instead you can see the profile from above. But it doesn't work!

The spawned instance of Firefox didn't load cookies, or addons, or anything. It's like a fresh version every time. I also tried to use instead of `firefox_profile`, `profile`, or `"moz:profile"`. I  even tried to import the profile as a `base64` string with `fs`. Nothing really worked. Maybe I just write it wrong?

**How can I include a Firefox custom profile using WebdriverIO?**

**!!! Edit:** Also tried the following `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\Prnlx0rh6w.bookmarks_player`

I also tried with double backslashes, but ended up with the same result. I tried to install Firefox Addon, but each new start it disappears. Also cookies are not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as `firefox_profile`:
"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\greerg.profile"

Comment: thank you for your awnser but sadly it is the same result. I also updated the question accorded to your awnser.